# XAMPP public server Ipv6 is avaible only locally

Tags: networking, router, webserver, ipv6, xampp

i had few years ago IpV4 based server, but since they turned my internet to IpV6 configurable only, i wasn't be able to get it working, I can access my XAMPP Domain locally with IpV6 address using http://[2a02:8071:2285:5200:54de:3e11:eff1:5c26]/ which works perfectly for LAN, but I need that it will be accessible from every place.

This is what i have in my system32/../hosts

```
2a02:8071:2285:5200:54de:3e11:----:---- zaktam.ddns.net
```

and this is my httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
ServerName dummy-host.example.com
ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "H:/Sites/ZAKTAM"
ServerName zaktam.ddns.net
</VirtualHost>
```

my ipconfig (I deleted It because It showed my private infos)

IpV4 which is detecting by internet sites, IP: 46.5.2.---

And Router settings:

(IpV6 Forwarding, Port Triggers, Firewall)

[image], [image], [image]

now my question, what did i configured bad so it only let's me to connent per LAN ?

I already found answer, It's because of my Internet provider which block this feature for normal people, and allow only Bussiness users do that.

Comment: Forwarding isn’t really what you do with IPv6. What does the “Port Filters” page offer?

Comment: Also: You’re using a temporary address (probably made by Privacy Extensions). It’ll expire after a set time. Instead, use the first address (`...::5`).

Comment: Here is what "Port Filters" say [link](https://s02.justpaste.it/files/justpaste/d342/a12927307/file1.png)

Comment: Wow, that looks, uh, super helpful. xD Well I guess you better refer to grawity’s answer. I don’t have the regular cable modem, so I don’t have experience with it.

Comment: You need a better router. Or at least better router firmware. That thing looks like complete garbage.

Comment: I know guys, that's why i gave up 2 years ago and didn't develop my Internet site anymore :c, It was so nice and cool to have IPv4 and host small servers to play with friends and do Internet sites :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: You're using a *temporary* address, which Windows changes every 10 hours. For hosting a server, you should instead use the permanent `2a02:8071:2285:5200:4184:29ad:791d:----` address.

Second: "Port forwarding" only happens when someone tries to connect to *router's own* IP address (which I'm guessing is `2a02:8071:2200:0:7d10:6245:ac1e:----`). But to be honest, port forwarding is a bit useless in IPv6 since you can just use your own address instead.

That's what you tried, actually, but it didn't work for a different reason – it didn't work because your router actually blocks all incoming connections to the LAN; that's the "IPv6 Firewall Protection" option.

Comment: I did all of that, but still I can connect only locally, I just found out that i have DS-lite :/

Comment: @zapole That only affects incoming IPv4 connections. I have IPv6 (Unitymedia) and still can't connect, so... :D